# Splitting Telegram messages with RegExp

Tags: python, regex, telegram

I have a file that holds extracted messages on Telegram. Each message starts with the date, has time, username and the message he/she sent:

```
08.04.2018 15:50:14, Vlada: Ey, hello there.

hows it going?
Everything fine?

08.04.2018 15:53:30, Other: Meh
could have been better.

08.04.2018 15:55:20, Vlada: ok
```

Now, I want to split this big string (from a file) into substrings that will be inserted into the python list, in such way that each entry of the list will be the message, with date, time and username, stored in a list. Something like this:

```
list = [
  '08.04.2018 15:50:14, Vlada: Ey, hello there.\n\nhows it going?\nEverything fine?\n',
  '08.04.2018 15:53:30, Other: Meh\ncould have been better.\n',
  '08.04.2018 15:55:20, Vlada: ok'
]
```

I will later perform some additional logic on those strings, but first I have to sort them in that manner.

**My attempt**

I went and start searching the date pattern at the start of the log, with that, I included all newlines with any characters and I want them all until I hit another date pattern.

```
/(\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4})(?s)(.*)(?=(\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}))/g
```

What I struggle is the ability of "how to loop over those elements" with reg expressions in order to achieve the result I mentioned above, and with a method that I have come up with, it doesn't include the last message at all.

Another thing I wanted to try is to find the start and end of the first message, insert a string into a list, and then delete that whole string from a file, but I feel that that is not the very good way of doing this.

*I use Python 2.7, Windows 10.*

Comment: To find all matches in a string you can use `re.finditer()` or `re.findall()`. Deleting a string at the beginning or somewhere in the middle of a file would need to rewrite the modified file completely so it isn't a good idea.

Comment: To also match last message, try to change `(?=(`...`)` to `(?=(`...`|(?!.))`

Comment: @MichaelButscher I like the sound of that

Comment: @MichaelButscher I have tried using those methods but none of them work properly. Here is an example of one of them [on here.](https://repl.it/repls/BruisedBestUpgrade)

Answer (score 1):

This solution was tried in a MacAir with Pyton 2.7.10. It should be close enough to Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

SOLUTION:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read()

import re

p = re.compile('(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},(?s).*?)(?=\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},|$)')

l = p.findall(data)
```

RESULT:

```
[
'08.04.2018 15:50:14, Vlada: Ey, hello there.\n\nhows it going?\nEverything fine?\n',
'08.04.2018 15:53:30, Other: Meh\ncould have been better.\n',
'08.04.2018 15:55:20, Vlada: ok'
]
```

DETAIL:

First, data.txt has your data, and it is read as a string into a variable named `data`. The regular expression:

```
(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},(?s).*?)(?=\n\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},|$)
```

is compiled. The `(?s)` matches the remainder of the pattern with the `s`, DOTALL, flag, which makes the `.` match any character, including newlines. The regular expression is very similar to the one you tried, except that it uses the `?` after the `*` to make it non-greety. Also, it uses the `|` to make `$`, end-of-string, an alternative end to the match.

Finally, `findall()` is used to find all substrings where the RE matches, and returns them as a list.

EDIT: I added a `\n`, new line, character to the regular expression right after the "positive lookahead," `?=`, in order to eliminate the empty line between messages from the result. This as a result from the comment from @lenik so that my result would exactly match your "Something like this:" list.

Also, I removed the output from my execution on a bash shell since it wasn't essential, especially since you are using Windows 10.

Comment: why are there double new line characters at the end of every message?

Comment: @lenik the new line characters were there in the original Telegram messages, and therefore in my data.txt file. There is one `\n` at the end of every line, including the empty lines. There is no empty line after the last line because the file ended right after the `ok`. I didn't remove any characters in the messages. They were just placed in a list, all characters from the beginning of a date to before the next date or before the end-of-string.

Comment: you should check the OP requirements and sample output

Comment: OK @lenik. I edited the result to remove the empty line between messages, the second new line character, `\n`, at the end of the first and second messages.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler approach, that gives the required result:

```
import re

result = []
for i in data.split('\n') :    # data -- is your original text
    if re.search( r'^\d\d\.\d\d\.\d\d\d\d', i) is None :
        result[-1] += '\n' + i
    else :
        result.append(i)
```

Assuming `data` has your original text, the result:

```
[
    "08.04.2018 15:50:14, Vlada: Ey, hello there.\n\nhows it going?\nEverything fine?\n", 
    "08.04.2018 15:53:30, Other: Meh\ncould have been better.\n", 
    "08.04.2018 15:55:20, Vlada: ok"
]
```